# how can you disable container recycling in windows 8 app?

Tags: wpf, xaml, user-interface, windows-8, ui-virtualization

If you have time, create a new **Blank App (XAML)** template and write the following XAML code.

I think creating a **WPF Application** is useless, because it appears as if container recycling doesn't work. Besides, *GridView* must be replaced with *ListView*.

```
<Page.Resources>
  <vm:MainViewModel x:Key="Main" />
</Page.Resources>

<Page.DataContext>
  <Binding Source="{StaticResource Main}" />
</Page.DataContext>

<Grid Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
      VerticalAlignment="Center">
  <Grid.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="GridViewStyle1"
           TargetType="GridView">
      <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
          <ControlTemplate TargetType="GridView">
            <ScrollViewer HorizontalSnapPointsAlignment="Near"
                          HorizontalSnapPointsType="MandatorySingle">
              <ItemsPresenter VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Standard" />
            </ScrollViewer>
          </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
    </Style>
  </Grid.Resources>
  <GridView Style="{StaticResource GridViewStyle1}"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
            SelectionMode="None">
    <GridView.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                    Loaded="StackPanel_Loaded">
          <Grid Width="800"
                Height="400">
            <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
                          VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
              <Border Background="#b7d84b">
                <TextBlock Foreground="Black"
                           Text="{Binding Message}" />
              </Border>
            </ScrollViewer>
          </Grid>
        </StackPanel>
      </DataTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemTemplate>
  </GridView>
</Grid>
```

Create the view-model and the *Item* class:

```
public class MainViewModel
{
    private const int NumberOfItems = 10000;

    public ObservableCollection<Item> Items
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        var tempCollection = new ObservableCollection<Item>();

        for (var index = 0; index < NumberOfItems; ++index)
        {
            var item = new Item
            {
                Id = index,
                Message = GetMessage(index)
            };

            tempCollection.Add(item);
        }

        Items = tempCollection;
    }

    private string GetMessage(int index)
    {
        var sb = new StringBuilder();

        for(var i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
        {
            sb.Append("...\n");
        }

        sb.Append("This is item #");
        sb.Append(index);

        return sb.ToString();
    }
}

public class Item
{
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

When you start the app, you can scroll through a series of items. I notice that when you scroll a specific item vertically so that you can see the "This is item #x" message, you will see another message "This is item #x" again after scrolling to the right (although you didn't scroll the item vertically.)

This is because the items are virtualized. And when an item becomes realized, a container is used from a pool. And if you have bad luck, the container is already scrolled...

There are 10 items in the pool:

[image: program output in code behind file]

The code behind file:

```
private readonly DateTime _start;

public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    _start = DateTime.Now;
}

[Conditional("DEBUG")]
public void WriteDebugMessage(string message)
{
    var span = DateTime.Now - _start;
    Debug.WriteLine(
        "{0:D2}:{1:D2}:{2:D3} - {3}",
        span.Minutes,
        span.Seconds,
        span.Milliseconds,
        message);
}

private void StackPanel_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    WriteDebugMessage("StackPanel loaded.");
}
```

Next, I recast the ItemsPresenter object:

```
<ItemsPresenter VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Standard"/>
```

If it worked, it wouldn't improve performance.

Does anyone know an elegant solution to the problem? I don't want to be fired because of too many public fields ;) I also thought about writing an attached property...

Answer (score 0):

**Updated:**

I still don't know why

```
<ItemsPresenter VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Standard"/>
```

doesn't work. So my latest solution is a hack. Besides, scrolling to the left may display an item that is put back, although you already scrolled it vertically. I use an attached property in MainPage.xaml.cs to define the vertical offset for each vertical *ScrollViewer*:

```
public static double GetVerticalOffset(DependencyObject obj)
{
    return (double)obj.GetValue(VerticalOffsetProperty);
}

public static void SetVerticalOffset(DependencyObject obj, double value)
{
    obj.SetValue(VerticalOffsetProperty, value);
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty VerticalOffsetProperty =
    DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("VerticalOffset", typeof(double), typeof(MainPage), new PropertyMetadata(-1.0, OnVerticalOffsetPropertyChanged));

private static void OnVerticalOffsetPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var sv = d as ScrollViewer;
    if (sv != null)
    {
        sv.ScrollToVerticalOffset((double) e.NewValue);
    }
}
```

Every time data for a specific item is requested in a data virtualization solution, the item's *VerticalOffset* property is set to 0. This triggers the delegate because of the default value of -1.